# How to read filename from response - reactJs

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, httpresponse

I'm downloading a file from a server. There I'm setting a file name which I would like to read on a frontend. Here is how I'm doing it on server:

```
string fileName = "SomeText" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + ".csv";

return File(stream, "text/csv", fileName);
```

Basically I will return different types of files, sometimes `csv` sometimes `xlsx`and sometimes `pdf`. So I want to get filename on a frontend so I might save it as it should be for example `SomeText.pdf` it will be saved automatically on local machine as `pdf`.

Here is my frontend code:

```
getFileFromServer(params).then(response => {
  console.log('server response download:', response);
  const type = response.headers['content-type'];
  const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: type, encoding: 'UTF-8' });
  //const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = 'file.xlsx'; // Here I want to get rid of hardcoded value instead I want filename from server
  link.click();
  link.remove(); //  Probably needed to remove html element after downloading?
});
```

I saw in Network tab under Response Headers that there is a `Content-Disposition` which holds that info:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="SomeText22/08/2019 10:42:04.csv";
```

But I don't know is it available in my response and how can I read it in my frontend part so I might replace

```
link.download = 'file.xlsx';
```

with Path from a server ..

Thanks a lot guys

Cheers

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue. I send the content-disposition header from the back-end and i can see it in the browser's network tab as well. But i'm unable to retrieve it in my code. It is not there in the ```response.headers```. Both answers below didn't work for me.

Comment: @Muaz I've created switch case on a frontend, created enumeration with possible file extensions, I'm sending that export type to a server when I'm looking for a file for example ".txt", ".csv", ".xlsx" and when I get response I'm just assigning that type which is being selected on the frontend to the file name and that is it,

Answer (score 4):

this is a special type of header so to get this header in frontend the backend person should allow from his end. then you can the headers in the response

```
response.headers.get("content-disposition")
```

the below code I have used in my project

```
 downloadReport(url, data) {
    fetch("url of api")
      .then(async response => {
        const filename = response.headers
          .get("content-disposition")
          .split('"')[1];
        const text = await response.text();
        return { filename, text };
      })
      .then(responseText => this.download(responseText))
      .catch(error => {
        messageNotification("error", error.message);
        throw new Error(error.message);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the filename from Content-Disposition on client side(frontend) you must give permission from server side(Backend). Spring users can use

```
@CrossOrigin(value = {"*"}, exposedHeaders = {"Content-Disposition"})
@Controller
@RequestMapping("some endpoint")
```

in their controller class.

Then from frontend we can get filename using.

```
const filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1];
```

Hope this helps. Above solution worked fine for me

Comment: Method is not generic, please check other cases https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 3):

You can get `filename` from `Content-Disposition` header by this way

```
getFileFromServer(params).then(response => {
  // your old code
  const [, filename] = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=');
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = filename;
  // your old code
});
```

Hope this will help